# Does uniroot.all() in R package 'rootSolve' employ Bisection method or Newton-Raphson method?

Tags: r, numerical-methods

The uniroot.all() function within the 'rootSolve' R package is an extension of the uniroot() base R function to find multiple roots of a nonlinear equation.

uniroot() uses the Bisection method. I am assuming that unroot.all() also employs the Bisection method; however, the R documentation for unroot.all() lists references for the Newton-Raphson method, which is confusing.

Within uniroot.all(), there are no arguments referring to the derivative of the function of interest, which suggests to me that unroot.all() uses the Bisection method.

Does anyone know which method uniroot.all() actually implements?

Comment: I don't see any reference to Newton-Raphson in the documentation for uniroot.all.  It also just calls uniroot directly so just bisection I guess...

Comment: I believe that `multiroot` of the same package uses Newton-Raphson, though.

Comment: I will do some more digging to find out for certain.